# Commit didn't work, but it did, but could not see it until sync. Why?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, synchronization, commit, stage

I'm learning about Github based off another training where the goal is to have training material synced via git between my Windows machine, where I edit them with VS Code, and a linux box where I do a git pull to get the changes and run the code.

The problem was that the first two test changes worked fine (edit the file in VS Code, stage, commit) and showed up in the repository. Doing a git pull from the linux box did update the local files.

Then it stopped. I worked on a few files, did a stage and commit and nothing happened. The VS Code console was not showing any errors, but the repository and the linux "git pull" commands did not show any changes. (this is commit 3)

I then added some more test changes and the same thing; stage, commit, no error, but the repository showed no difference, no update. (this is commit 4 and 5)

Then I did a stage and sync and there! Commits 3, 4, and 5 showed up in the repository!

So what happened? Does github have a time limit or commit amount limit I do not know? Or does sync do something special?

Why could I not see the commits 3, 4 or 5 before the sync? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There was a confusion in my understanding of how git and github are sructured.
Short answer: I was not pushing to the github repository.
Long answer: I had not understood the function of github and git and did not even think github and git were seperate.
As such, when I was staging, I thought that my changes are now ready. Then with a commit, I expected them to appear in my github repository, when in fact the commit was just adding them to the LOCAL depository.
I was commiting, but I was not pushing. And I was expecting my commits to show up in the github repository.